# Cant Access Bootstrap WYSWYG from code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap wsywyg editor but I am having problems in .net getting its values. I am Running the editor in my asp.net webpage with materpage with the following markup

```
<div class="box">
            <div class="box-header">
              <h3 class="box-title">Bootstrap WYSIHTML5 <small>Simple and fast</small></h3>
              <!-- tools box -->
              <div class="pull-right box-tools">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-widget="remove" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
              </div><!-- /. tools -->
            </div><!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body pad">

                <textarea id="txtDescription" name="txtDescription"  class="textarea" placeholder="Place some text here" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;"></textarea>

            </div>
          </div>
 </div>
```

Howver I have treid the following to gain access to the text behind code

> 1. Request.Form["txtDescription"] But the Value is null baring in mind my entire page is wrap in  the following code.

```
<form id="main" runat="server">
           <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cptUniteCmsContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder></form>
```

Just wondering if anyone else new how to gain access to it. Must I referance my masterpage some how as If I try to use find control it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to indicate runat="server" for each of your controls.
**For instance**:

```
    <textarea id="txtDescription" name="txtDescription"  class="textarea" placeholder="Place some text here" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;"></textarea>
```

**Needs to be changed to:**

```
    <textarea id="txtDescription" name="txtDescription"  class="textarea" placeholder="Place some text here" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;" runat="server"></textarea>
```